# Web Crawler for testing purpose?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, testing, web, web-crawler

I want to test a set of ruby-on-rails applications. Specifically, I want to trigger all possible `GET/POST` requests available. I am considering using some web crawler-like tool, which could (recursively) send requests to my web server, get responses, and parse the response HTML file to get all possible "href tags", "form submission buttons", etc.

Essentially I want to see the performance of these web applications and get some logs of things like what are the request routes, parameters, database accesses, queries, transactions, etc.

Sending `GET` requests is relatively easy to handle, I would need to simply parse the HTML response and extract the `href` attributes of all anchors. However, I don't know how to handle those POST requests; they would require me to fill in all these parameter fields included in the form fields. I am wondering if there exist some tools doing such work. Or some tools I can easily modify (not too much) code to achieve my functionality?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596518/automated-link-checker-for-system-testing?